# Use .csv as data source with PHP

Tags: php, csv

With PHP I want to pull in some text from a comma separated csv file (my array) on my server.  Dependent on the text (title) that is pulled into a page from a variable.

i.e.

```
<div><?php echo $item->title;?>
<div>Prices from £[php price here]</div>
```

Where 'title' in the echo (above) could be Spain.

So my csv would have:

```
Spain, 250
France, 350
Germany, 150
```

Spain being the 'title' and '250' being the [php price here] I want to pull in.

So if Spain were the 'title' being pulled in, it would grab the price of 250.

i.e.

```
Spain
Prices from £250
```

Hope this makes sense...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example. Assumning you have you file with data called `pricelist.csv`.

```
$pricelist = array();
if (($handle = fopen("pricelist.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $pricelist[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($pricelist); echo '</pre>';
```

Will give you output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Spain
            [1] =>  250
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => France
            [1] =>  350
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Germany
            [1] =>  150
        )
)
```

Now you will be able to use this array data.

Comment: cool.. that's great.
I now have the array output as above being pulled into my page.
How do I now get this array output into the following code:
<div><?php echo $item->title;?>
<div>Prices from £[php price here]</div>
Thanks

Comment: What is the `$item` object? What framework do you use to pass variables into templates? Do you use templates?

Comment: I'm using joomla...
What I am trying to do now that I have the array output is to print just that price for the corresponding title <?php echo $item->title;?>.
So if <?php echo $item->title;?> = Spain, print 250.
Thanks

Comment: Never worked with joomla. But I think you should be able to pass this array as a variable into you `view` template and use it there. Maybe something like `$this->assignRef('pricelist', $pricelist);`. And then access it via `$this->pricelist`.

Comment: Thanks...
Still can't get the last bit.
This is my full code:
   <a class="Title" href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">
    <?php echo $item->title;?>
   </a>
   <?php
       $pricelist = array();
       if (($handle = fopen("townprices.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
       {
          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
          {
             $pricelist[] = $data;
          }
          fclose($handle);
       }
       echo '<pre>'; print_r($pricelist); echo '</pre>';
       ?>

I just need to pull in the price 'if' <?php echo $item->title;?> matches a csv entry.

Comment: I assume I would use "if (in_array..." but how to implement

Answer (score 0):

To question with so little detail, I can only answer with a link to http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function, you can use it to read in the csv file to an Array.

Comment: Thanks... but not being a php dev, this doesn't really help as I don't know what else to do with my 'if' statement for the different 'title's that could be pulled in that I want to associate with a price in the csv.

Comment: @user991830 Could you edit your post with the code that you have. Then someone may be able to help you further.

Comment: @user991830 Without being an a-hole I'd like to suggest that if you don't have a grasp on some of the basic programming concepts needed to attempt this task you'd be better served to hit some tutorials and **learn** a bit before rushing to Stack Overflow to get free code. And check out the links deceze posted in his comment.